# Extjs 4 how create a combobox with size = 4 as select tag in html

Tags: extjs

I'm using Ext Designer. Does ExtJS supports a component like this?

[image]

Comment: What have you come up with so far? Do you understand the ExtDesigner generates? Did you read the docs on Ext.ComboBox? Do you know how the component works?

Comment: I think my question is so confused. I just want to know, Is extjs support a component like this http://www.techotopia.com/images/a/aa/Javascript_selection_list.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Ext JS does support a component like this, it's called the [Grid](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel).

Drgomesp is right that ComboBox won't do such a thing out-of-the-box, but there's no need to as there are other components for this.

You might also try [Ext.ux.form.MultiSelect](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/multiselect/multiselect-demo.html) which is even more like HTML `<select>`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna assume you are using ExtJS 4.

First of all you need to know that Ext.form.field.ComboBox is not based on the select html tag, but the input of text type tag.

With that said, even if you manage to do that by hacking the base CSS class of the component, you would need to come up with something to show multiple rows in the combo, and allow the selection of those.

Apart from that, you would need to work with the default button that comes with the ComboBox, by definition a background image set on the `x-form-trigger` class.

Comment: So the simple answer is Extjs is not support that kind of component? I mean built-in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ext.view.BoundList](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.view.BoundList). It's used in extjs combobox as popup.